# Content Query Webpart custom styling for group items

Tags: sharepoint

I have a custom  list(Course Detail) in SharePoint 2010 site collection which consists of following columns

1. Course ID
2. Course Title
3. Semester (its a drop-down menu that consists of values e.g. Semester1, Semester2 upto Semester8)

I used content query web-part to display this list items on a page.

My problem is that I want to apply custom group styling on CQWP items through XSLT. The default group style that CQWP gives contains group heading on top of each group item but I want that this heading will be on right most column of each group items with row-span.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define a custom item style by updating the appropriate files and setting the item style accordingly in your CQWP.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bb447557.aspx

You will need to have an idea on how to work with XSLT for this to work. If you have done any data view web parts you should be somewhat familiar with this already.